# Use credentials inside docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm building a docker image from a project where I have a file with default credentials for the database. At the docker container run time, I want to pass the real credentials and replace the variables defined on that file. What is the best way to do it? I tried to use environment variables, but it's not working.

db_config.yml:

```
host: ${HOST}
user: ${USER}
pass: ${PASS}
port: ${PORT}
db: ${DB_NAME}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  test_ctr:
      container_name: test
      image: container:latest

      network_mode: "host"
      environment: 
      - HOST=${HOST}
      - USER=${USER}
      - PASS=${PASS}
      - PORT=${PORT}
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
```

db_config.yml is in builded image and language is Python. Basically when I run container, db_config.yml is red by a script and use file's credentials. When I create the image, this db_config.yml have default credentials. but when I run the container, I want to replace this file

Comment: Can you show us what you've done with env vars ? There is no reason it should not work as this is how it's done for various popular images (MySQL for example)

Comment: can you please provide more info?

Comment: is the db_config.yml in the docker image?  what is the project language ruby, java or bash?

Answer (score 1):

To debug this try running:

```
docker exec -it <name-of-the-container> <command>
```

In your case this translates to:
    docker exec -it test sh

This should open a shell inside the container.
Then type:

```
printenv
```

This will print all Environment variables and their values (that way You will see if the values You have passed are present)

There will be a problem if the container is crashing at startup (in this case it's not possible to use docker exec).

TIP:
Use .env file located in the same directory as docker-compose.yml (or whatever your docker-compose file is) to pass variables.

.env:

```
KEY1=value1
KEY2=value2
```

In your case this might look something like:

```
HOST=1.2.3.4
USER=sa
PASSWORD=42
PORT=4242
DB_NAME=mydb
```

When your running:

```
docker-compose up
```

docker-compose will look for this .env file and will inject the values from this file

Good luck

Comment: But how do I reference env variables inside my file? ${VARIABLE} is correct ?

Comment: In docker-compose You can use:
HOST=${HOST}
or
HOST=$HOST
or even something like:
HOST_PORT="${HOST}:${PORT}" (if You want to interpolate)
This will inject the variables into the container, but now your app has to read them and that depends on the mechanisms used by a specific framework. I have seen Java app using config similar to your db_file.yml, but that was because Spring has understood this syntax and it knew that it has too take the values from Environment Variables. Please make sure that your framework also supports this.